# Problemas ao Ler Arquivo em C - delimitador vírgula

Tags: c, arquivo

auxílio por gentileza.

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de linha de arquivo:

```
99933311133,UM NOME QUALQUER,8485885855,UM ENDERECO QUALQUER,84 9992212,S,S
```

O padrão é: string-virgula-string-virgula-string-virgula-string-virgula... Ou seja, cada campo está separado por uma vírgula.

Para fazer a leitura, intencionei capturar linha por linha com o fgets e, em seguida, fazer a atribuição do valor a cada variável utilizando o fscanf, ficando assim:

```
while (fgets(linha, TAM_BUFFER, arq)) { // lê cada linha do arquivo por vez, cada linha está na variável buffer
    fscanf(arq, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]\n", cpf, nome, cnh, endereco, contato, ind_brasileiro, ind_estado_civil);
```

No fgets cada linha do arquivo é armazenada na variável "linha", como uma tripa.

No fscanf a variável arq é a variável com o arquivo aberto em modo leitura.

Esta solução não está nem próxima do que necessito pois o resultado é catastrófico:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém teria uma ideia do que fazer para corrigir?

O que quero que apareça na tela é um texto assim: "CPF: 123456666, nome: Fulano de Tal, número da CNH: 939393939393....".

Comment: Como está a impressão dos dados?

Comment: **Talvez** seja o caso de ler a linha com `fgets` e usar a função `strtok`

Comment: Fiz a impressão de cada campo e está vindo de forma correta. Então eu mudei a string e agora está vindo quase que corretamente. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a função `strtok()` da biblioteca padrão `string.h` para "quebrar" a linha em campos.

A função a seguir é capaz de dividir a string `src`, usando o delimitador `delim` e retorná-la em forma de uma array de strings:

```
char ** strsplit( const char * src, const char * delim )
{
    char * pbuf = NULL;
    char * ptok = NULL;
    int count = 0;
    int srclen = 0;
    char ** pparr = NULL;

    srclen = strlen( src );

    pbuf = (char*) malloc( srclen + 1 );

    if( !pbuf )
        return NULL;

    strcpy( pbuf, src );

    ptok = strtok( pbuf, delim );

    while( ptok )
    {
        pparr = (char**) realloc( pparr, (count+1) * sizeof(char*) );
        *(pparr + count) = strdup(ptok);

        count++;
        ptok = strtok( NULL, delim );
    }

    pparr = (char**) realloc( pparr, (count+1) * sizeof(char*) );
    *(pparr + count) = NULL;

    free(pbuf);

    return pparr;
}
```

Em seguida, você pode abstrair os campos do seu registro em uma estrutura de dados:

```
struct record_s
{
    char * cpf;
    char * nome;
    char * cnh;
    char * endereco;
    char * contato;
    char * ind_brasileiro;
    char * ind_estado_civil;
};

typedef struct record_s record_t;
```

Como a ordem dos campos do seu registro em arquivo é sempre a mesma, a seguinte implementação é capaz de mapear o campo com o membro da estrutura, convertendo a linha lida para uma estrutura de dados preenchida:

```
record_t * parse_record( char * linha )
{
    char ** pp = NULL;
    record_t * cad = NULL;

    pp = strsplit( linha, "," );

    cad = (record_t*) calloc( 1, sizeof(record_t) );

    cad->cpf = strdup(pp[0]);
    cad->nome = strdup(pp[1]);
    cad->cnh = strdup(pp[2]);
    cad->endereco = strdup(pp[3]);
    cad->contato = strdup(pp[4]);
    cad->ind_brasileiro = strdup(pp[5]);
    cad->ind_estado_civil = strdup(pp[6]);

    strsplitfree( pp );

    return cad;
}
```

Colocando tudo Junto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINE_MAX_LEN            (1024 * 2)   /* 2 KBytes */

struct record_s
{
    char * cpf;
    char * nome;
    char * cnh;
    char * endereco;
    char * contato;
    char * ind_brasileiro;
    char * ind_estado_civil;
};


typedef struct record_s record_t;


char ** strsplit( const char * src, const char * delim )
{
    char * pbuf = NULL;
    char * ptok = NULL;
    int count = 0;
    int srclen = 0;
    char ** pparr = NULL;

    srclen = strlen( src );

    pbuf = (char*) malloc( srclen + 1 );

    if( !pbuf )
        return NULL;

    strcpy( pbuf, src );

    ptok = strtok( pbuf, delim );

    while( ptok )
    {
        pparr = (char**) realloc( pparr, (count+1) * sizeof(char*) );
        *(pparr + count) = strdup(ptok);

        count++;
        ptok = strtok( NULL, delim );
    }

    pparr = (char**) realloc( pparr, (count+1) * sizeof(char*) );
    *(pparr + count) = NULL;

    free(pbuf);

    return pparr;
}


void strsplitfree( char ** strlist )
{
    int i = 0;

    while( strlist[i])
        free( strlist[i++] );

    free( strlist );
}


record_t * parse_record( char * linha )
{
    char ** pp = NULL;
    record_t * cad = NULL;

    pp = strsplit( linha, "," );

    cad = (record_t*) calloc( 1, sizeof(record_t) );

    cad->cpf = strdup(pp[0]);
    cad->nome = strdup(pp[1]);
    cad->cnh = strdup(pp[2]);
    cad->endereco = strdup(pp[3]);
    cad->contato = strdup(pp[4]);
    cad->ind_brasileiro = strdup(pp[5]);
    cad->ind_estado_civil = strdup(pp[6]);

    strsplitfree( pp );

    return cad;
}


void destroy_record( record_t * cad )
{
    free(cad->cpf);
    free(cad->nome);
    free(cad->cnh);
    free(cad->endereco);
    free(cad->contato);
    free(cad->ind_brasileiro);
    free(cad->ind_estado_civil);

    free(cad);
}


void show_record( record_t * cad )
{
    printf( "[ REGISTRO ]\n" );
    printf( "   CPF: %s\n", cad->cpf );
    printf( "   Nome: %s\n", cad->nome );
    printf( "   CNH: %s\n", cad->cnh );
    printf( "   Endereco: %s\n", cad->endereco );
    printf( "   Contato: %s\n", cad->contato );
    printf( "   Ind. Brasileiro: %s\n", cad->ind_brasileiro );
    printf( "   Estado Civil: %s\n", cad->ind_estado_civil );
    printf( "\n" );
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    char line[ LINE_MAX_LEN + 1 ];
    record_t * c = NULL;
    FILE * fp = NULL;

    fp = fopen( argv[1], "r" );

    while( fgets( line, LINE_MAX_LEN, fp ) )
    {
        c = parse_record( line );
        show_record( c );
        destroy_record( c );
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Entrada.txt:

```
12312312300,JOSE SILVA,56548656,SAO PAULO,(11) 999991234,S,N
98798798700,MARIA SOUZA,32443234,RIO DE JANEIRO,21 978783434,S,S
88877766600,JOAO CARLOS,78645554,BRASILIA,61 945454532,N,N
99933311133,UM NOME QUALQUER,8485885855,UM ENDERECO QUALQUER,84 9992212,S,S
```

Testando:

```
$ ./teste entrada.txt
[ REGISTRO ]
   CPF: 12312312300
   Nome: JOSE SILVA
   CNH: 56548656
   Endereco: SAO PAULO
   Contato: (11) 999991234
   Ind. Brasileiro: S
   Estado Civil: N


[ REGISTRO ]
   CPF: 98798798700
   Nome: MARIA SOUZA
   CNH: 32443234
   Endereco: RIO DE JANEIRO
   Contato: 21 978783434
   Ind. Brasileiro: S
   Estado Civil: S


[ REGISTRO ]
   CPF: 88877766600
   Nome: JOAO CARLOS
   CNH: 78645554
   Endereco: BRASILIA
   Contato: 61 945454532
   Ind. Brasileiro: N
   Estado Civil: N


[ REGISTRO ]
   CPF: 99933311133
   Nome: UM NOME QUALQUER
   CNH: 8485885855
   Endereco: UM ENDERECO QUALQUER
   Contato: 84 9992212
   Ind. Brasileiro: S
   Estado Civil: S
```

Comment: Eu acho que nas primeiras 4 palavras da resposta eu já sabia que você era o autor =]